# Spring Filter for handling exceptions

Tags: java, spring

I want to handle certain exceptions in spring and wrap the **REST** response into another object format.

So I came up with the idea of using filters and checking the response status code, for example if it's 400, it means **Bad Request** so I can wrap the response into the JSON format I need, here is the code sample :

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

        if(((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).getStatus() == 400){

            servletResponse.resetBuffer();
            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setStatus(200);
            servletResponse.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            PrintWriter out = servletResponse.getWriter();
            out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new IgResponseDto<>(IgResponseCode.BAD_REQUEST, "en")));
        }
    }
```

Is it a good way to wrap the response for certain exceptions inside filters and what are the disadvantages of such a case?

Comment: No it isn't ... Use an ExceptionHandler for that which is designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are ready made tools for that, so you don't have to do your custom made code. I used `@ControllerAdvice` annotation that allows me to create a single class that handles any uncaught exception that came from any Controller. In that class I can have several methods where each method handles a particular exception or a group of exceptions. But this is only one way to deal with exceptions. Here is a very good article that describes all available tools and standard ways to handle errors: [Error Handling for REST with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)